# Google Sheet App Script Dropdown List set by Header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My goal is to populate a column with a dropdown that references values in another workbook. I was able to adapt a script to work however as my destination column may occasionally move I am trying to get the dropdown to populate in a column based on the column header in the destination workbook. For example, I want the dropdown to populate sizes from another workbook in the column in my destination workbook that has the header SIZE.

The source workbook can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FIxPPtI_kcq_PZoA0fLBizxK6AHg7nftEjZM1Dmc4Gs/edit#gid=0) and the destination workbook can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EmSfNV9y_xfGiDtds8DwScWAfnY6zHwICmHAqp9zRk/edit#gid=0).

The following script works with the exception of finding the correct column based on the header in the destination workbook and it that the dropdown is not keeping the required format. In the source workbook the number is formatted as 0.000 however this is not retained in the destination workbook and changing the format in the destination workbook results in an error.

```
  function dropdown() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Destination workbook    
  const dst = wb.getSheetByName("Database");
  const dropDwn="E2:E"; //<<< Cell address where Drop Down currently goes

  var remoteID="1FIxPPtI_kcq_PZoA0fLBizxK6AHg7nftEjZM1Dmc4Gs"; //<<<File ID of source workbook
  var remoteSh="Tb_UnitSize"; //<<<Sheet name in the source workbook

  var data, rule;
  data=SpreadsheetApp.openById(remoteID).getSheetByName(remoteSh).getDataRange().getValues();//<<< all data on remote sheet
  data=data.map(function(x) {return x[0];}); //<<<column A on remote sheet
  data=data.filter(function(x) {return x!='';});//<<<only non-blank cells
  dst.getRange(dropDwn).clearDataValidations();//clear existing data validation, if any
  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(data).build();
  dst.getRange(dropDwn).setDataValidation(rule);
}​
```

[image]

Comment: This question is a copy of [App Script Dropdown reference Header ](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/224143447). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
function dropdown() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Destination workbook    
  const dst = wb.getSheetByName("Database");
  
  const headerColumn = dst.getRange(1,1,1,dst.getLastColumn()).createTextFinder("SIZE").matchCase(true).findNext().getColumn(); //<<< Column number  where Drop Down currently goes

  var remoteID="SPREADSHEET_ID"; //<<<File ID of source workbook
  var remoteSh="Tb_UnitSize"; //<<<Sheet name in the source workbook

  var data, rule;
  data=SpreadsheetApp.openById(remoteID).getSheetByName(remoteSh).getDataRange().getDisplayValues();//<<< all data on remote sheet
  data=data.map(function(x) {return x[0];}); //<<<column A on remote sheet
  data=data.filter(function(x) {return x!='';});//<<<only non-blank cells
  dst.getRange(2,headerColumn, dst.getLastRow()).clearDataValidations();//clear existing data validation, if any
  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(data).build();
  dst.getRange(2,headerColumn, dst.getLastRow()).setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

Changing the `.getValues()` to `.getDisplayValues()` to also get the format of your data.

Also to find the column header "SIZE" you need to use the `CreateTextFinder()` with getColumn to return the column of the string you are looking for. This will return the Column Index, so you need to modify the getRange to use it as a column index not as the actual column letter.

Comment: Now, I noticed that you have already posted an answer with the same modification point with me. I apologize for this.

Comment: @MicahNoble hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function xvalidations() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("validation source ssid");
  const vsh = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vvs = vsh.getRange(1, 1, vsh.getLastRow(), vsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const vobj = {};
  vvs.forEach(r => {
    vobj[r[0]] = [r[1], r[2], r[3]]
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vobj));
  return vobj;
}

function loadValidations() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const obj = xvalidations();
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearDataValidations();
  const vs = rg.getValues().forEach((r,i) => {
    obj[r[0]]
    sh.getRange(i + 2, 2).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[r[0]]))
  });
}
```

Datavalidation source values on Sheet1

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 | a | b | c |
| 2 | P2 | d | e | f |
| 3 | P3 | g | h | i |
| 4 | P4 | j | k | l |
| 5 | P5 | m | n | o |

My Sheet0

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 |
| 2 | P1 |  |
| 3 | P2 |  |
| 4 | P3 |  |
| 5 | P4 |  |
| 6 | P5 |  |

[image]

[image]

In regard to your question try this:

```
function loadValidations() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const obj = xvalidations();
  const hdr = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  const col = {};
  hdr.forEach((h,i) => col[h] = i + 1);
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearDataValidations();
  const vs = rg.getValues().forEach((r,i) => {
    obj[r[0]]
    sh.getRange(i + 2, col["header name"]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[r[0]]))
  });
}
```

Comment: Cooper, I am getting an error:
Exception: Argument cannot be null: values
(anonymous) @ cooper.gs:23   >       sh.getRange(i + 2, col["SIZE"]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[r[0]]))
loadValidations @ cooper.gs:21  >   const vs = rg.getValues().forEach((r,i) => {

Comment: Here is a link to an image showing the error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GAv4UTktnXO_Xx02HbJiBjSsMTShDDlx/view?usp=drive_link